# NLog optional or empty mail recipient

Tags: email, nlog

In my NLog [Mail target](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Mail-target) configuration, the values for the `to` and `cc` parameters are being set dynamically, and sometimes, the value for `cc` will be empty. This results in no mail being sent, even though the `to` parameter contains a valid email address. Furthermore, there are no errors to be found in NLog's internal log file.

An example configuration:

```
<variable name="to" value="test@test.com"/>
<variable name="cc" value=""/>

<target
    ...
    to="${to}"
    cc="${cc}"
```

NLog's internal log:

```
2015-01-19 14:55 Debug Setting 'MailTarget.name' to 'mail'
2015-01-19 14:55 Debug Setting 'MailTarget.smtpServer' to 'smtp'
2015-01-19 14:55 Debug Setting 'MailTarget.to' to 'test@test.com'
2015-01-19 14:55 Debug Setting 'MailTarget.cc' to ''
2015-01-19 14:55 Debug Setting 'MailTarget.from' to 'from@test.com'
```

How can I use an optional or empty recipient in an NLog Mail target configuration?

Note: I'm currently using a workaround, but it feels a bit dirty and I would prefer not to use it in a production environment.

```
<variable name="cc" value="a@b"/>
```

Comment: I haven't heard about this issue before. Could you open an issue at Github?

Comment: Opened a new [issue](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/507) at GitHub.